# How to insert a yaml string into a yaml value as if it is yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I need some help with python.
I have two arrays: param_keys and param_values. The first one contains string keys and the second one contains base64 encoded strings.
I also have an existing yaml structure i read from a file:

```
start:
  implementation: ansible.cloudify_ansible.tasks.run
  inputs:
    playbook_path: ansible/main-routers.yaml
    run_data:
      hostname: r1
```

I want to add those key-value pairs into the existing yaml under the "run_data" key. The problem is that my values are not simple strings but they're yaml in form of a base64 string:

Original yaml

```
- index: 1
  address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_1 }
  netmask: 30
- index: 2
  address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_2 }
  netmask: 30
```

Base 64 encoded string:

```
LSBpbmRleDogMQogIGFkZHJlc3M6IHsgZ2V0X2lucHV0OiBob3N0X2lwX2ludF9uaWNfcjFfMSB9CiAgbmV0bWFzazogMzAKLSBpbmRleDogMgogIGFkZHJlc3M6IHsgZ2V0X2lucHV0OiBob3N0X2lwX2ludF9uaWNfcjFfMiB9CiAgbmV0bWFzazogMzA=
```

Here's my code:

```
with open(blueprintPath + "ansible_" + str(ansible_id) + ".yaml") as f:
    doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
    for key,value in zip(param_keys,param_values):
        decodedstring = base64.b64decode(value).decode('utf-8')
        doc["start"]["inputs"]["run_data"][key] = decodedstring
with open(blueprintPath + "ansible_" + str(ansible_id) + ".yaml",'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

Here's what I get:

```
start:
  implementation: ansible.cloudify_ansible.tasks.run
  inputs:
    playbook_path: ansible/main-routers.yaml
    run_data:
      hostname: r1
      ip_config: "- index: 1\n  address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_1\
      \ }\n  netmask: 30\n- index: 2\n  address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_2\
      \ }\n  netmask: 30"
```

My wish is to get this:

```
start:
  implementation: ansible.cloudify_ansible.tasks.run
  inputs:
    playbook_path: ansible/main-routers.yaml
    run_data:
      hostname: r1
      ip_config:
      - index: 1
      address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_1 }
      netmask: 30
      - index: 2
      address: { get_input: host_ip_int_nic_r1_2 }
      netmask: 30
```

where "ip_config" is an example of key in param_keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a single string in your output because you put the value there as single string. What you want to do is to parse the value as YAML and put the resulting value there:

```py
    doc["start"]["inputs"]["run_data"][key] = yaml.safe_load(decodedstring)
```

Comment: Think you very much! It was so simple and maybe I need to sleep more! :D